# Finding Match and Similarity between rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm Facing a problem design with my Oracle DB.
I have some **Samples** (Samples have unique names), each sample has some **Locus**(Locus have unique names). Inside each Locus, there is a string of **Allel** values like the example below:

```
+--------+------------+----------+
|Name    | Locus      | Allel    |
+--------+------------+----------+
|F70     | DX61       | 10,11,12 |
|F70     | DX60       | 10,12    |
|E70     | DX61       | 10,12    |       
|E70     | DX60       | 10,11,12 |
|S70     | DX61       | 11,13    |
```

What I need to do is this:

When I get a sample from user (SampleName, LocusName(s),Allel(s))), I need to find the Samples which are a match for my input value, Match means: there are no difference between Allel values of the corresponding Locus or Even they are different in 1 locus, it is still a match.
If 2 or more locus have different values, I need to find a percentage of similarity between them.
For example:
if input is:

```
+--------+------------+----------+
|Name    | Locus      | Allel    |
+--------+------------+----------+
|D70     | DX61       | 10,11,12 |
|D70     | DX60       | 10,12    |
```

F70 is a match. 
E70 is still a match since it is different than the input only in one locus.
S70 is not a match but now I have to calculate the similarity between values of Allels. S70 doesn't have Locus DX60, and it has one similar value in Allel in Locus DX61 so the similarity is 20% (2 Allels in DX60 are missing since it doesn't have it, only 1 Allel in DX61 is present so 1 in 5 is present).
What really confuses me is that the order of locus can be anything. Imagine that if I want to find all the matches for 1 input, I have to consider all the samples that have the Exact Locus(s) and have the exact Allel Values then I have to find all the samples that have all the locus and allel there is in the input but they can have mismatch in 1 locus or even doesn't have that locus.
one more point, Allel values are separated with the comma and they are stored as Varchar since Allel values are not limited to numbers and have values like O1 or L2 as well.
I will clarify any question you have, but Please try and help me solve this.
How Can I design queries to find these values? Should I do all the operations on the program side or server side?

Comment: I think I've seen this exact same question some time back today. *Deja vu*

Comment: You should fix your data structure to have one row per name/locus/allele.  Then this type of query would be much simpler.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What to you mean? I already have name/locus/allel already.

Comment: @GurV yes there was a mistake, I delete that instead of editing  :)\

Comment: @Guardian . . . You are storing alleles in a delimited string.  You are using a string to store a list.  That is bad.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes... Allels have stuff like O1 and L2 as well so I can't store in other values